# Prevent recursive calls of XmlHttpRequest to server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, meteor

I've been googling for hours for this issue, but did not find any solution.

I am currently working on [this](http://racetimer.meteor.com/) app, built on [Meteor](http://meteor.com/).

Now the scenario is, after the website is opened and all the assets have been loaded in browser, the browser constantly makes recursive xhr calls to server. These calls are made at the regular interval of 25 seconds.

This can be seen in the Network tab of browser console. See the Pending request of the last row in image.

[image]

I can't figure out from where it originates, and why it is invoked automatically **even when the user is idle**.

Now the question is, **How can I disable these automatic requests?** I want to invoke the requests manually, i.e. when the menu item is selected, etc.

Any help will be appriciated.

**[UPDATE]**

In response to the Jan Dvorak's comment:

When I type "e" in the search box, the the list of events which has name starting with letter "e" will be displayed.

The request goes with all valid parameters and the Payload like this:

```
["{\"msg\":\"sub\",\"id\":\"8ef5e419-c422-429a-907e-38b6e669a493\",\"name\":\"event_Coll_Search_by_PromoterName\",\"params\":[\"e\"]}"]
```

And this is the response, which is valid.

```
a["{\"msg\":\"data\",\"subs\":[\"8ef5e419-c422-429a-907e-38b6e669a493\"]}"]
```

The code for this action is posted [here](http://jsbin.com/eheduc/1/edit)

But in the case of automatic recursive requests, the request goes without the payload and the response is just a letter "h", which is strange. Isn't it? How can I get rid of this.?

Comment: Is that an app built by you? If so, you should post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I could write an answer about long requests but I can't find the code responsible for them.

Comment: Meteor has a cool feature that when you save an HTML, it automatically updates on the client. I suggest ditching Meteor if this can't be prevented on production.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, wait I'm updating the question

Comment: You are saying `25 miliseconds` What I'm observing is `25 seconds`. That's a big difference.

Comment: I guess they're used to reflect any changes that are supposed to be tracked by the client. These updates (see the screencast - changes to the database are reflected by all clients immediately) need long requests (or any other alternative to web sockets).

Comment: @jan Dvorak, yeah its actually 25 seconds, my mistake.

Comment: The thing is, we are not making any changes to database at all, the browser keeps on making requests on its own, even when it is idle.

Comment: I'll write about long requests

Comment: Sohel, you are trying to solve a non-existant problem. This is a feature of the Meteor platform. If you don't want this feature (live page updates, as Jan answered below, but also latency compensation and local mongo caching), then why are you using Meteor?

Answer (score 6):

Meteor has a feature called

> **Live page updates.**
>
> Just write your templates. They automatically update when data in the database changes. No more boilerplate redraw code to write. Supports any templating language.

To support this feature, Meteor needs to do some server-client communication behind the scenes.

---

Traditionally, HTTP was created to fetch dead data. The client tells the server it needs something, and it gets something. There is no way for the server to tell the client it needs something. Later, it became needed to push some data to the client. Several alternatives came to existence:

**polling:**

The client makes periodic requests to the server. The server responds with new data or says "no data" immediately. It's easy to implement and doesn't use much resources. However, it's not exactly live. It can be used for a news ticker but it's not exactly good for a chat application.

If you increase the polling frequency, you improve the update rate, but the resource usage grows with the polling frequency, not with the data transfer rate. HTTP requests are not exactly cheap. One request per second from multiple clients at the same time could really hurt the server.

**hanging requests:**

The client makes a request to the server. If the server has data, it sends them. If the server doesn't have data, it doesn't respond until it does. The changes are picked up immediately, no data is transferred when it doesn't need to be. It does have a few drawbacks, though:

If a web proxy sees that the server is silent, it eventually cuts off the connection. This means that even if there is no data to send, the server needs to send a keep-alive response anyways to make the proxies (and the web browser) happy.

Hanging requests don't use up (much) bandwidth, but they do take up memory. Nowadays' servers can handle multiple concurrent TCP connections, so it's less of an issue than it was before. What does need to be considered is the amount of memory associated with the threads holding on to these requests - especially when the connections are tied to specific threads serving them.

Browsers have hard limits on the number of concurrent requests per domain and in total. Again, this is less of a concern now than it was before. Thus, it seems like a good idea to have one hanging request per session only.

Managing hanging requests feels kinda manual as you have to make a new request after each response. A TCP handshake takes some time as well, but we can live with a 300ms (at worst) refractory period.

**Chunked response:**

The client creates a hidden iFrame with a source corresponding to the data stream. The server responds with an HTTP response header immediately and leaves the connection open. To send a message, the server wraps it in a pair of `<script></script>` tags that the browser executes when it receives the closing tag. The upside is that there's no connection reopening but there is more overhead with each message. Moreover, this requires a callback in the global scope that the response calls.

Also, this cannot be used with cross-domain requests as cross-domain iFrame communication presents its own set of problems. The need to trust the server is also a challenge here.

**Web Sockets:**

These start as a normal HTTP connection but they don't actually follow the HTTP protocol later on. From the programming point of view, things are as simple as they can be. The API is a classic open/callback style on the client side and the server just pushes messages into an open socket. No need to reopen anything after each message.

There still needs to be an open connection, but it's not really an issue here with the browser limits out of the way. The browser knows the connection is going to be open for a while, so it doesn't need to apply the same limits as to normal requests.

These seem like the ideal solution, but there is one major issue: IE<10 doesn't know them. As long as IE8 is alive, web sockets cannot be relied upon. Also, the native Android browser and Opera mini are out as well ([ref.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)).

Still, web sockets seem to be the way to go once IE8 (and IE9) finally dies.

---

What you see are hanging requests with the timeout of 25 seconds that are used to implement the live update feature. As I already said, the keep-alive message ("h") is used so that the browser doesn't think it's not going to get a response. "h" simply means "nothing happens".

Chrome supports web sockets, so Meteor could have used them with a fallback to long requests, but, frankly, hanging requests are not at all bad once you've got them implemented (sure, the browser connection limit still applies).

Comment: Nice-long-descriptive answer, But can't accept it, since its not a solution to the problem.

Comment: @SohelKhalifa I'm afraid it's impossible without not using Meteor. I'll try to look around, though. Why do you want to prevent these requests?

Comment: Simply to minimize the `request-handling` load on server.

Comment: @SohelKhalifa the only thing pending requests cost is memory, not CPU or disk I/O. Even then, the memory cost is negligible. Preventing live updates won't save you CPU. Concerning disk I/O, the majority of the disk access are static requests (jQuery, Meteor, CSS, images), not caching from the little extra memory. Pending requests don't cost bandwidth either (it's just one HTTP handshake per 25 seconds - you get more hits (and way more bytes) from other access.